# TransactionScope in xUnit tests does not work on AppVeyor

Tags: xunit.net, appveyor

I faced with a situation which I don't have a clue about its cause. I'm writing this thinking that somebody will face it again and use my solution. Or somebody had has faced with it and solved with better solution.

I use in-memory hosting to test my simple WebAPI. In tests I used TransactionScope to ensure DB does not retain the state. All such tests are executed synchronously so that concurrency issue in not the case. This approach work correctly locally (MSSQL Express 2014), but on AppVeyor it's not working (MSSQL Express 2016). I'm not sure if MS version makes sense here.

In order to solve the issue I removed usages of transaction scope and manually restore data state in the end of the tests. 
This build is failed [URL](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/xtrmstep/requiem-settingsservice/build/0.2.4/tests). You can see the state of the source on GitHub.
This build is passed [URL](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/xtrmstep/requiem-settingsservice/build/0.2.1.5/tests). The only difference is usage of transaction.

The questions to those who my know: WHY? Why does it behave this way on AppVeyor when locally it's OK?

Comment: Could you try to use MSSQL Express 2014 instead of 2016 to isolate SQL version cause? I see that you use UI for configuration, so you can change it on Settings > Environment > Services.

Comment: The changing to SQL2014 has solved the issue. But why? Does SQL2016 use some special mode or anything else?

Comment: If you're using xUnit 2, there are parallelism settings; you could be running in parallel even if your code is not explicitly doing that. See http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html for how one can make things run in serial (I have not [taken] the time to look at your repo). Aside from the parallelism settings, there chances are it's not going to be an xunit issue - it doesnt do anything with resources - it's going to be something that you're getting away with locally which is being exposed in the other context

Comment: This is not the case with parallelism since I'm using a collection fixture in xUnit. It forces all tests which belongs to that collections run synchronously. But maybe you're still correct that something is different between mine and AppVeyor configuration. 
How can I check that? Any ideas?

Comment: As I understand SQL server version is different between your and AppVeyor configuration. Does SQL2016 works locally for you?